# JMF java.util.NoSuchElementException not see my webcam

Tags: java, eclipse, webcam, capture, jmf

I want to capture image using my webcam in Java on ubuntu 11.10

```
         Vector deviceList = CaptureDeviceManager.getDeviceList( new RGBFormat());
        System.out.println(deviceList.toString());
        //gets the first device in deviceList
        device = (CaptureDeviceInfo) deviceList.firstElement();
```

I have exception "java.util.NoSuchElementException"

I installed jmf-2_1_1e-linux-i586.bin and i added  jmf.jar in reference libraries in my project.

My webcam correctly works.

What should i do that see my webcam?

Thank for helping

Answer (score 0):

Please check the Vector API, you can look that:

```
/**
 * Returns the first component (the item at index <tt>0</tt>) of 
 * this vector.
 *
 * @return     the first component of this vector.
 * @exception  NoSuchElementException  if this vector has no components.
 */
public synchronized Object firstElement()
```

The deviceList is empty. You should call the isEmpty() method before calling the firstElement() method. If the isEmpty() return true, you can't call the firstElement() method.

```
if(deviceList!=null && !deviceList.isEmpty()){
    device = (CaptureDeviceInfo) deviceList.firstElement();
}
```